# How to use ScrollView with CollectionView

Tags: ios, swift, uiscrollview, uicollectionview, swift4

I need to have a view controller that has a scroll in view.

The problem is that I need that both scrolls (of scrollView and collectionView) work together.
But when I add ScrollView in all frame, nothing works...

That's an image that shows what I want:

[image: scroll + collection]

And when I scroll viewController, all content scroll together..

Someone know a good way to implement this in swift 4?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Maybe add a photo of what you are wanting and some code about what you have attempted

Comment: @agibson007 I edited post.. Thanks!

Comment: So if the top scrolls when the users touches the view then it could all be a collectionView

Comment: No, because the itens that I need to insert needs to be outside collectionView

Comment: So the bottom scrolls under that?

Comment: Hmm There's no requires for this. Just need to be outside. It's better if everthing scroll equals.. But if you have an way to do like bottomSheet, I will appreciate too.

Comment: Maybe I am not understanding but if the entire thing scrolls why not just a UICollectionView with a header or a separate cell for what you are doing at the top?  No need at all for a UIScrollView.  Use the collection view for that

Comment: @agibson007 I have itens in viewController that is being so difficult to handle inside a collectionView header. One example, is add a avPlayerController inside a view. I can't do this inside the header.

Answer (score 0):

I've seen this done many ways. The most popular of which is to have these views embedded in a UITableView.

You can set the first cell height to a proportional amount to the superview, while keeping another cell that will contain your CollectionView. You would be able to take advantage of the UITableView's scrollView as well as it's memory efficiency and delegate.

Answer (score 0):

A better way to do this is to use the scroll direction in UICollectionViewDelagateFlowLayout. Just add the `UICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout` protocol or extends your ViewController to it. Then use `.scrollDirection` in the section of your UICollectionView.

And sample declaration like this

```
  let collectionView: UICollectionView = {
    let layout = UICollectionViewFlowLayout()
    ...
    layout.scrollDirection = .vertical //or .horizontal depends on your liking
    let cv = UICollectionView(frame: .zero, collectionViewLayout: layout)
    ...// 
    return cv
}()
```

then add to your view `view.addSubview(collectionView)`

More info in the apple [doc](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uicollectionviewflowlayout) or jump to definition